# Looking for NASNET classification code to train from Scratch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am looking for a NASNET classification code to train from Scratch on my own dataset. In Google Search, I found many GitHub repositories but I'm not sure those repositories can be used to train on my own datasets from scratch. If you have worked on any NASNET GitHub repositories and solved your classification problems please suggest.

Additionally, I would like to know how the datasets can be prepared for NASNET? In my case, I have a total of five class of images. Do I need to separate each class of images into the respective class folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following link (Nasnet in tensorflow)

```
https://github.com/yeephycho/nasnet-tensorflow
```